# How do I delete rows in a data frame based on another shorter vector?

Tags: r, vector, compare, matching

I have a data frame `data` with a column `item_code` which indicates for which item the observations in this row are. There are several observations/rows for the same products. Furthermore, I have a vector `item`, in which some of the item codes are saved. I need to delete the rows from my data frame which are for one of the items in `item`. The data frame has more rows than the vector.

I figured I probably have to use the `%in%` operator but I can't get it to work, I tried with

```
d2 <- data[which(item %in% item_code$data), ]
```

But then my data frame `d2` has only the length of the `item` vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the opposite. Negate your indexes or your boolean values

```
d2 <- data[-which(item %in% item_code$data), ]
```

or

```
d2 <- data[ ! item %in% item_code$data, ]
```

these differ in how they handle `NA` values but you really didn't supply sample input and desired output so it's not clear what you would expect in those cases